# Move Outlook Emails between Outlook folders via Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Below is just one of the many code examples that I've tried to modify to suit.

```vb
Sub MoveItems()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("test")
    Set myItems = myInbox.Folders("TODO").Items
    For i = myItems.Count To 1 Step -1    'Iterates from the end backwards
        myItems.Item(i).Move myDestFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to modify this code to reference the specific Outlook folders that I have set up.

I have two folders outside of the Inbox folders named "TestA" & "TestB".
Via the Rules in my Outlook, I've extracted whatever e-mails that I need from my Inbox to "TestA".
Within my Excel file, I've extracted all of the info that I need from those e-mails.

At this point I only need to move via Excel, 'all' of the emails in "TestA" to "TestB".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your VBA macro is designed to be run in Outlook. If you automate Outlook from Excel you need to differentiate `Application` objects from the Outlook object model and Excel. To control Outlook objects from outside Outlook, you must establish a reference to the Outlook object library from the project in which you are writing code. To do this, use the `References` dialog box in the Visual Basic Editor in the primary application. You can then write code that returns a reference to the Outlook Application object. Through this reference, your code has access to all the objects, properties, methods, and constants defined in the Outlook type library.

There are several ways to return a reference to the Outlook Application object.

- Use the `CreateObject` function to start a new session of Outlook and return a reference to the Application object that represents the new session.
- Use the Visual Basic `GetObject` function to return a reference to the Application object that represents a session that is already running. Note that because there can be only one instance of Outlook running at any given time, `GetObject` usually serves little purpose when used with Outlook. `CreateObject` can always be used to access the current instance of Outlook or to create a new instance if one does not exist. However, you can use error trapping with the `GetObject` method to determine whether Outlook is currently running.
- Use the `New` keyword in several types of statements to implicitly create a new instance of the Outlook `Application` object by using the Set statement to set an object variable to the new instance of the `Application` object. You can also use the New keyword with the `Dim`, `Private,` Public`, or` Static` statement to declare an object variable. The new instance of the Application object is then created on the first reference to the variable.

Basically, after adding a COM reference to the Outlook object model you can write the following in Excel VBA:

```
Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application 
' Set the Application object 
Set objOLApp = New Outlook.Application
```

Note, if you need to get folders at the same level with `Inbox` you need to get the `Parent` folder of the Inbox folder and then use the `Folders` collection to get the required folder. The [Folder.Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.parent) property returns the parent object of the specified object, typically the parent of the `Folder` object is the `Folders` collection object.

```
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
Set myInbox =  myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
Set inboxParentFolder = myFolder.Parent
Set mySpecificFolder = inboxParentFolder.Folders("TestA")
For Each mailitem In mySpecificFolder.Items  
     ..... do some stuff.....
```

That works only if you deal with the default store (delivery store). If you need to get the Inbox folder of the specific store in the profile, you need to use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

```
Sub MoveItems()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object
Dim outlookApp = New Outlook.Application()
Set myNameSpace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set parentInboxFolder = myInbox.Parent
Set myDestFolderA = parentInboxFolder.Folders("testA")
Set myDestFolderB = parentInboxFolder.Folders("testA")
Set myItems = myDestFolderA.Items
For i = myItems.Count To 1 Step -1    'Iterates from the end backwards
    myItems.Item(i).Move myDestFolderB
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Kudos for the detailed explanation that will likely prove invaluable going forward with my project besides just fixing the code to work.

Answer (score 1):

If your folder is a peer of Inbox, go one level up to the Inbox parent, then one level down:

```vb
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Parent.Folders("TestA")
```

You can also get there from any folder, not just the Inbox using `Store.GetRootFolder`:

```vb
Set myDestFolder = AnyFolder.Store.GetRootFolder().Folders("TestA")
```